# Excel to Python for big panel data, regression ready format?

Tags: excel, panel, regression, analysis

Trying to get some big panel data from excel into python so I can do some GMM/Cross sectional panel data regression analysis (think sci-kit package). I have moved my data from excel to Python but the format for regression analysis is not correct (see below). The Scikit website has some datasets on there to play with, but it is not really helpful for discussing formats and how to get your data into a similar format to get my data into Python.

Does anyone have any experience using excel (.xlsx) data and getting it into Python, 'regression-ready'?

I have already done my needed regression analysis in R and Stata, but I would like to get better at using Python for regression analysis, since it has some nice attributes.

Here is my dataframe format so far, from excel to Python. 
(this is truncated from a 10,000 X 60 shape dataset)

```
   BANKS  YEARS     CIR         DSF   EQCUS     EQLI     EQNT      EQUITY  
0     CR1   2005   65.46   927915.00  28.553   23.948   37.542  264946.50   
1     CR1   2006   65.98  1026491.00  30.491   26.584   36.143  312986.00   
2     CR1   2007   60.26  1437615.00  27.003   23.413   28.238  388197.20   
3     CR1   2008   58.08  1605464.00  24.024   20.160   25.828  385696.80   
4     CR1   2009   65.21  1538570.00  28.160   22.850   27.907  433267.30   
5     CR1   2010   54.45  1822863.00  31.009   24.555   28.274  565254.60   
6     CR1   2011   57.38  2075505.00  30.905   24.861   29.618  641440.50   
7     CR1   2012   62.12  2533641.00  29.595   24.509   28.883  749821.50
```

Data types:

```
>>>df.dtypes

BANKS                   object
YEARS                    int64
CIR                    float64
DSF                    float64
EQCUS                  float64
EQLI                   float64
EQNT                   float64
EQUITY                 float64
```

Unicode in the columns (I don't think sci-kit likes that!)

```
>>>df.columns.tolist()

[u'BANKS', u'YEARS', u'CIR', u'DSF', u'EQCUS', u'EQLI', u'EQNT', u'EQUITY']
```

Comment: I don't see any problem with the dataset. It's a pandas dataframe and it can be used in scikit-learn. What is the issue you face when using this dataset?

Comment: I guess on the scikit-learn page, I don't see any documentation for inputting excel data. All I see is their datasets already loaded in and then they begin to extract features, and fit the model. How who I run a basic OLS for this data above? I do not see this anywhere on the scikit page. Statsmodels has similar documentation issues.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure which columns you're including in the regression, or what errors you're getting, but you can't use categorical variables in regressions (like 'BANKS'). You need to convert the categorical var to dummy vars (binary 0/1) and exclude the original categorical variable from your regression.

I also don't believe you can include rows with missing data points, so you either need to impute the data or drop the rows. (df.fillna in pandas)

You may want to consider using pandas to manage datasets in python. It's a package you can install and import in python, and makes python behave more like R or STATA. There's a nice tutorial here: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/10min.html

Pandas even has a function for converting categorical variables into dummy variables: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.get_dummies.html

Hope that helps...

Comment: Thanks for the links! I use pandas now. The 'banks' variable is not used as a regressor but to indicate panel data. I just need a little help with a regression of this data in the format it is in. I am very surprised information on regressions in Python is so scant, when it comes to importing in data via 'stata' or 'R' form.

Comment: I prepared the data via pandas, see my other questions, as I used 'melt', 'pivot' and 'groupby' commands. At this moment I am just looking to run regression, OLS to get my data moving around via sci-kit.

Comment: no problem :) what is the problem that you're running into?